# How can I store the name of selected objects in a text file?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I would like to create an automatic list of the objects that have been selected with the mouse click.
So for example I have cube1, cube2, cube3, cube4.

I select them in the following order cube3, cube2, cube4, cube1 then a list on a text file shoud be generated in the order that they have been selected 3,2,4,1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer to this question is not as straight forward as you would expect. Blender is not storing the selection order for objects. It only stores the active object and a sorted list of all other objects. So what you really need is a way to catch all selection events. One way to do that is using a modal operator like this:

```py
import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_record_selection(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Records the selection order while running and when finished with ESC saves it to //order.txt"""
    bl_idname = "object.record_selection"
    bl_label = "Record Selection"

    origSel: None
    selOrder: None

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.mode == 'OBJECT'

    def modal(self, context, event):
        # Update selection
        curSel = context.object

        # On selecting new object
        if curSel is not self.origSel:
            self.report({'INFO'}, 'Selection was changed')
            self.origSel = curSel
            self.selOrder.append(context.object)
        elif event.type in {'RIGHTMOUSE', 'ESC'}:
            # Use this to save to an internal text data block
            if "order.txt" not in bpy.data.texts:
                bpy.data.texts.new("order.txt")
            bpy.data.texts["order.txt"].clear()
            bpy.data.texts["order.txt"].write('\n'.join([obj.name for obj in self.selOrder]))
            
            # Use this for saving to a text file
            #try:
            #    with open(bpy.path.abspath("//order.txt"), 'w+') as f:
            #        for obj in self.selOrder:
            #            f.write("%s\n" % obj.name)
            #    self.report({'INFO'}, 'Saved order to file at ./order.txt')
            #except Exception:
            #    self.report({'ERROR'}, 'Error while writing to file at ./order.txt')
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.origSel = context.object
        self.selOrder = []
        if context.object is not None:
            self.selOrder.append(context.object)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}


def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_record_selection.bl_idname,
        text="Record Selection",
        icon='RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_record_selection)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_record_selection)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_select_object.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hello, I've tried the script in 2.8 and is not working. How should I use it?

Comment: did you copy the accidental marks in the last row? (I just removed them) It should work by opening it in a blender text editor and pressing "Run Script" Then it should make the modal operator available in the search menu and in Viewport > Select > Record Selection

Comment: Can confirm that the script works fine.

Comment: Thank you @HenrikD, is perfect. Can I use it in my add-on?

Comment: sure thing. How is it called?

Comment: @HenrikD Is not something finished is just a draft. Something like "Name Selector". One more question how can I generate the txt file inside blender text editor? I've tried to modify that absolute path with '''bpy.data.texts.new(new.txt)''' but is not working.

Comment: I updated the code to include a section for both cases

Comment: @HenrikD Thank you.

Comment: Hi @HenrikD I know it sounds stupid but how can I add the objects between " " I'm able to add the coma.

Comment: Found the answer: ' " ' +obj.name+' " '

Comment: '"%s"'%obj.name would also work well